# Transfer incoming php request to another server

Tags: php, multithreading

I have two servers that runs the api from my app. Every single request arrives to my Main Server, let's called server A. Some files that requires more processing I want it to send to another server, server B.

I call the other server by executing a curl_url, but the PHP file on server A stays alive and waiting until server B finish, which is more than 30secs.

My questions are:

1-. Is there any other way to re-direct that process to server B. I try with hatches, but because it upload a file, I can only pass POST data and no FILES

2-. Is there any way to put to sleep the PHP file on server A until server B finish and gives a response?

I can't do this process on server A, because take allot of resources and we want that the API response faster, and if many people call that process that take allot of time to complete, our server A will be too crowd, in the worst case with the server B working, only that process will be affected.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about moving it out of PHP all together?

If you are using Apache you could accomplish this with mod_proxy with a simple configuration like:

```
ProxyPass /slow_script.php http://otherserver.com/slow_script.php
```

Comment: Hi @teacurran what do you mean moving it out of PHP all together?about  ProxyPass will be using CPU process on server A or only on server B or both?

Comment: Unless you redirect the request to another domain "http://serverb.yourdoain.com", you are tying to proxy a request through server A to server B.  So it is always going to consume resources on both servers until it completes. ProxyPass is just a lighter weight proxy than using curl_url.  The best approach is to have server A acknowledge the request and put the hard work into a queue, then have server B check the queue for work to do. Without knowing what you are trying to do though I can't get into specifics.

Comment: Hi, terrence, What I'm trying to accomplish is that when my users call the a specific function on the API that creates a video, it takes about 30 seconds to finish. and if many people call that same function eventually the server will be really slow. That's why I want to move this specific function to another server, in the worst case that function will be slow and the rest of the API will be working perfectly fine. I need to give an answer to the user that request the video from the API when it finishes, that's why I can't use a background strategy

Comment: If many users can make server A slow, they will make server B slow eventually as well.  The only way to prevent this and be able to scale is to queue the video creation. Usually this is done by telling the user it is queued, then you can do an ajax request or something every few seconds to see if the video is ready. This enables you to have encodes take longer or 2, 3, ...., 10 server b's if your traffic gets really high.

Comment: Yes But the API some time are used in mobile apps, so I can't create a request to check if video is completed. I know that eventually server B will be slow, but server B only serve one service, in work case only the video creation will be slow but the rest of the API will be working perfectly